# How to stop deleted Alert that continues to generate alerts

Tags: sharepoint-online, online, m365

I have deleted a SharePoint alert on behalf of another user (as an admin).  The User Alerts area shows only "None" as an option from the User Alerts list, however the alert continues to send emails to a group. I have checked with the user who created the alert and each of the recipients, none of them show as having alerts from their view. How can I stop the alerts once and for all?

Comment: If you are a site admin, you can check all alerts from the site settings. check: [view and delete alerts for another users](https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-view-or-delete-sharepoint-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#ID0EBJ=Modern). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I am an admin. Yes I looked at User Alerts and deleted them.  The problem is in spite of  having updated the list and deleting the alerts resulting in no ALERTS left in the list,  the alerts continue to send emails when there is activity in the library.